# How do I create a filtered Dropdown Choice field in Django using ajax?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-forms

I am trying to create a dynamic filtered drop down choice fields,i gone through below blog but it confusing,can any one suggest easy way to do this in django.

I'm trying to create a dynamically filtered dropdown Choice field in Django. I've tried [the steps outlined here](http://www.nerdydork.com/dynamic-filtered-drop-down-choice-fields-with-django.html), but I don't understand it.

How do I create a filtered Dropdown Choice field in Django using ajax?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use dajaxproject (django+ajax). Example: http://www.dajaxproject.com/forms/ It's so easy.

Comment: Application Error appears... => down?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean something like this?
http://code.google.com/p/django-ajax-selects/

I have this implemented in a couple of projects, and it's working well. If you are looking for a kind of search form for foreign keys, have a look at an app I started some weeks ago:

https://github.com/schneck/django-foreignkeysearch

Answer (score 0):

I only had a small array of drop down choices I needed to display, so I chose to be lazy and not to go the Ajax route but rather used the initial example provided in the blog (his prototype). This will slow down rendering the page if you have many drop-down choices, which I do not have.

The way it worked for me was that I replaced the array:

```
modelstxt[1] = "1\tEscort\n2\tTaurus";
modelstxt[2] = "1\tAltima\n2\tMaxima";
```

With template tags that will create the same array while building the page (note I use locations and areas, not models and makes):

```
areastxt[0] = "0\t--";
{% for location in locations %}
   areastxt[{{location.id}}] = "0\t--
   {% for area in areas %}
      {% if area.location_id == location.id %}
         \n{{area.id}}\t{{area.name}}
      {% endif %}
   {% endfor %}";
{% endfor %}
```

Disclaimer: I am noob'ish, so I may be committing a noob faux-pas using this approach.